# Does there exist mathematical background for ultra-slow process control?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, chemistry, nonlinear-dynamics

I want to ask a question to respected mathematicians and specialists in control theory:
Is there a separate direction in nonlinear control theory that develops control of super slow processes? Are special control algorithms known, etc.? Is there a (at least initial) mathematical background for this?

Example: ball rolling along a predetermined path at a speed of 1 cm per day, taking into account friction.

Comment: What technical challenges would arise in the control of slow processes? I don't see any.

Comment: Direct drive telescope. That drive includes an induction motor, a support platform and other components. If we imagine this system in the state-space, we get a non-stationary dynamic model with slowly changing parameters, taking into account friction, etc. It is necessary to minimize the speed of movement from point A to point B algorithmically. This is not a task from the university or anything like that. Just a small research project and a desire to delve deeper into control theory.

Comment: I think your question is too broad and should be broken into several questions. Since this is Math SE, here you can ask about the control of slowly-changing systems of a specific form. Show the ODEs, please. At [Engineering SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com), you can ask about sensors and actuators. I assume that the computation part is trivial.

Comment: I need at least some hints in the mathematical field, which is aimed at a slowly changing process. And yet, in a nutshell, I understood from your words that it is necessary to study the differential equations that describe these processes. What methods are used, what is investigated, etc.? In addition to this, I do not know, and I need to have some specific guidance in this area. So let's get started with math

Comment: Have you consulted a book like Khalil's [Nonlinear Systems](https://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearSystems)? Is there anything specific you need and that is missing from Khalil's book?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with this book. In this book I did not find slow processes, their differential equations, the features of their research and analysis.

Comment: There are control theorists on Math SE. I am not one of them. If your question did not interest them, you may be doing something wrong. Finding a way to "sell" the question to the controls people may teach you something useful.

Comment: Yes, maybe you're right. Either that, or the topic somewhere "floats", but is expressed in other formulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in this topic, I recommend looking for the keyword phrase "Slow-Fast Dynamic". I felt that a separate direction in control theory exists ...